# Errors and Warnings while building Wireshark

Tags: c, build, msbuild, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am trying to build Wireshark on Windows by following the steps given here - https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChSetupWin32.html . But I am running into weird errors and warning during building Wireshark. The errors I am getting are described below.

```
 "C:\Development\wsbuild64\Wireshark.sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\text2pcap.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (44) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\text2pcap.vcxproj" (default target) (90) ->
   (ClCompile target) ->
     C:/Development/wsbuild64/text2pcap-scanner.c(993): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file ge
   nerated [C:\Development\wsbuild64\text2pcap.vcxproj]


   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\Wireshark.sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\wiretap\wiretap.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (56) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\wiretap\wiretap.vcxproj" (default target) (87) ->
     C:/Development/wsbuild64/wiretap/ascend.c(429): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file gener
   ated [C:\Development\wsbuild64\wiretap\wiretap.vcxproj]
```

I am also getting some warnings which are described below.

```
"C:\Development\wsbuild64\Wireshark.sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\text2pcap.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (44) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\text2pcap.vcxproj" (default target) (90) ->
   (ClCompile target) ->
     C:/Development/wsbuild64/text2pcap-scanner.c(993): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro
    invocation 'text2pcap_wrap' [C:\Development\wsbuild64\text2pcap.vcxproj]


   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\Wireshark.sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\wiretap\wiretap.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (56) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\wiretap\wiretap.vcxproj" (default target) (87) ->
     C:/Development/wsbuild64/wiretap/ascend.c(429): warning C4273: 'malloc': inconsistent dll linkage [C:\Developm
   ent\wsbuild64\wiretap\wiretap.vcxproj]
     C:/Development/wsbuild64/wiretap/ascend.c(436): warning C4273: 'free': inconsistent dll linkage [C:\Developmen
   t\wsbuild64\wiretap\wiretap.vcxproj]
```

I tried building the thing by using the following command so that I do not get the warning as an error. But I still get the same error and the build fails -

```
msbuild /m /warnasmessage:C2220 /p:Configuration=RelWithDebInfo Wireshark.sln
```

What can be done in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone faces the same issue, make sure that you have installed all the required packages before you attempt to build Wireshark. In this case, I forgot to install Perl, Bison and Flex.